# Mozilla plugin for remote desktop protocol

Tags: plugins, activex, mozilla, remote-desktop, rdp

Is there a remote desktop plugin for mozilla browsers that can perform remote desktop functionality from with the browser. Similar to the ActiveX control found in Terminal Services Web.

IE similar to this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=E2FF8FB5-97FF-47BC-BACC-92283B52B310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/windows-all.html#Techinline

[Google Results](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=firefox+plugin+remote+desktop&aq=f&oq=%3Ffirefox+plugin+remote+desktop&aqi=&aq=&oq=&aqi=&fp=OzgK0dwM7rU) for "Firefox Plugin Remote Desktop"

Comment: not free. it costs money